# processing 2 different agents in the same machine and storing the 2 different agents in the same machine in anylogic

Tags: anylogic

Below is the Problem;

I want to build the simulation Block for the below use case.

**Step 1** - I have a source which gives input (Part 1) to Machine 1.

**Step 2** - Machine 1 then processes the Part 1 and Produces Part 2.

**Step 3** - Part 2 is then stored in Queue 1.

**Step 4** - from Queue 1 , Part 2 is then again sent to Machine 1, where it processes the Part 2 and produces      Part 3. I want to give priority to Part 2 over Part 1.

**Step 5**- Part 3 is then sent to Queue 1.

**Step 6** - from Queue 1 only the Part 3 goes to sink.[image]

What did I try;

I am blocked about executing the model. Can anyone please give the best approach for this problem?

Thanks,
Vinayak

Comment: Welcome to SOF. This place works best for you if you ask very focused, specific questions on 1 AnyLogic issue, show exactly what you tried already and where you are stuck. If you want to know “how do I best do X in AnyLogic”, you should use the LinkedIn forum instead. Check this overview to the community to understand why: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-community. Else, try to break down your broad question into specific sub-questions and ask them separately, see https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow.

Comment: Also, check my workshop on doing stuff like this: https://youtu.be/OWwjKqKUA1A?si=OG7ewlytujOPyh2H